# Can't import jar from MavenLocal into Android Studio - UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on a project where we have written separate libraries for our end points/apis, in pure Java.

To include these libraries we use the companies setup, a site called artifactory, and we upload our jars there.

When we use gradle we can import them easily and everything works properly and my world is good.

However, to make any debug changes to these libraries I am faced with committing the code to git, kicking off a build with our Jenkins CI, then pushing the compiled jar up to artifactory. This not only takes a few mins it also pollutes the git history and creates tens of unnecessary jar files.

One of my colleagues has managed to get around this by choosing PublishToMavenLocal, from within the library. He changes out the gradle compile line in dependencies for his local SNAPSHOT jar.

When I and another colleague try this we get the following error.

```
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

the full stack trace I have included at the end.

when looking up the two diff errors (finished with non-zero exit value 1 and UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION) I have come across two main theories.

non-zero exit : this is when a project has duplicate dependencies on a specific library. This seems doubtful to me as it in theory is the same library, it's just being hosted somewhere different.

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL : this seems to be when conflicting versions of Java are being used. Our libraries are written in Java 1.8 and the app is in 1.7. I have a feeling this is where the problem lies, but I have tried publishing the library to MavenLocal after switching the library to 1.7 too. I'm not an expert with this publishing to MavenLocal by any means, so it could easily be something I've done wrong here, but I am at a loss as to what.

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:542)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\t... 12 more","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:569)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\t... 12 more","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"2 errors; aborting","sources":[{}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to build using Java 7.  Looks like its failing to load a class

```
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
```

Edit you libraries are written in Java 8 but this is not supported by Android.  Try building the libs targeting Java 7

Comment: Hi, this seems to have worked, though I am puzzled as our libraries have lambdas in so I assumed that they wouldn't work under java 7? And when you say build you mean build/publish the jar to my MavenLocal, right?

Comment: Correct. When you compile the Java library be it through gradle, maven or some other way.

Comment: Then how can it work using Java 7 when we have lambdas?

Comment: You have to recompile the library using Java7.  You can't have lamdas.  Using lamdas will cause the byte code to be written in a way that is only understood by Java 8.  Since Java 8 is not supported when trying to build the dex it looks for version of the class file format used.  If that version is above the supported version then you will get a fail with the `bad class file magic` message